# Problems writing to a file in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write to a txt file using prolog so I tried making a simple predicate to test that, here it is:

```
writefacts():-
    open('output.txt', write, Out),
    write(Out, 'test'),
    close(Out).
```

The problem is that when I run it, on SWI-Prolog (AMD64, Multi-threaded, version 8.2.1), all I get is **true** and nothing on the output.txt.

I've already tried looking for similar questions, but all I learned is that this code should be working. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you get `true`, then all the predicates succeeded. So the `output.txt` file should be created with the word test in it. Is the file not created?

Comment: It is working for me on `swi-prolog` same version and arch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not check your code but it does look correct.

Odds are it wrote to a directory different than what you expected.

To see the directory that SWI-Prolog is currently using as the working directory you can use either of these predicates.

```
?- pwd.
% c:/users/groot/documents/prolog/
true.
```

or

```
?- working_directory(D,D).
D = 'c:/users/groot/documents/prolog/'.
```

HTH

---

For more details see this [post](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/prolog-8-3-2-gui-can-not-find-likes-source-file/2542/6?u=ericgt) in the [SWI-Prolog forum.](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/)

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the problem.